# How to monitor physical disk instance writeload on windows server ? Only _Total is working

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-sbs-2008, perfmon

I'm trying to measure the writeload of 2 RAID volumes using the provided instance performance counters. Hence only the "_total" marked ones create performance data, the instance counters do not. I can see the Physical Disk instances with the assigned drive letters and can select them. But no data seems to be recorded. I would like to see wether "normal" SSDs would be capable of handling the load in our rather low duty scenario.

The system is a Dell server with a Dell SAS 6/IR controller. Is there something I'm missing ?